# Spring Application deployment giving an error

Tags: java, spring, jdbc

I am trying to deploy a war file of a web project created using spring boot on JETTY server(8.1.4).

The deployment is failing with following exception,

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jdbc/DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceTransactionManagerAutoConfiguration.transactionManager()] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager cannot be cast to org.springframework.transaction.PlatformTransactionManager
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1095)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:990)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:504)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:475)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:298)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:193)
```

I am not able to get the root cause for this exception.

My `pom.xml` is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>org.healthfidelity</groupId>
<artifactId>HFIam</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>HFIam</name>
<description> application</description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<dependencies>

    <!-- Spring dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test tools -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
        <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring security -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- LogBack dependencies -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
        <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.7</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- JAVA mail dependency -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Templating engine -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.velocity</groupId>
        <artifactId>velocity</artifactId>
        <version>1.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Spring ldap -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Porticor utility -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>PorticorUtility</groupId>
        <artifactId>PorticorUtility</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!--Others -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Dependencies used for testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.subethamail</groupId>
        <artifactId>subethasmtp</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.7</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <start-class>org.healthfidelity.hfiam.Application</start-class>
    <java.version>1.6</java.version>
</properties>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Please share your context definition

Comment: You have issues in either your dependencies or class-path. We need to know more about the project. Share POM (if using Maven) and some information on your deployment.

Comment: please post spring.xml

Comment: I dont have `spring.xml` I have configured my beans using java based configuraitons.

Answer (score -1):

I've never used Spring boot but it clearly says it needs a transaction manager.  Depending on how you're accessing your DB you need something like:

```
@Bean
public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager() throws Exception {
    JpaTransactionManager txManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
    txManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
    return txManager;
}
```